# In a report how do I add a filter of type String having comma seprated values e.g. 'Cats,Dogs'?

Tags: reporting, filters, string

Salesforce considers 'Cats,Dogs' as 'Cats' or 'Dogs'. [This link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpQYAAY) suggest putting the string value inside double-quotes, which I've already tried without any success.

Comment: please provide the literal example that you tried, because I tried to replicate and the suggested solution seems to work fine..

Comment: "Cats,Dogs" - didn't work. That's an example.

Comment: You might understand that when the exact same thing works fine for me (and also for others, judging from the link you provided) there is probably some other factor besides only the filter parameter that influences your results. So to properly answer your question, some additional information is needed. What's the complete query like? And what fieldtype is the field that you are filtering on "Cats,Dogs"? And please provide a screenshot where you are applying the filter.